# Integrating AWS Lex with Skype

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

I have created a Chat bot in AWS LEX and want to integrate it with Skype. Is there any way I can achieve that?

I have already implemented it with Facebook, Slack, and Twillo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying using [LexRuntime](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html),
 [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-overview) and [AWS SDK for Javascript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html) to implement Amazon Lex over skype for business in Node.js.

You can define as:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var lexruntime = new AWS.LexRuntime({ apiVersion: '2016-11-28' });
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    console.log(session.userData);
    var params = {
        botAlias: '$LATEST', /* required */
        botName: 'YourBotName', /* required */
        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', /* required */
        inputStream: session.message.text,//new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' || streamObject, /* required */
        userId: 'username', /* required */
        accept: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        sessionAttributes: session.userData /* This value will be JSON encoded on your behalf with JSON.stringify() */
    };
    console.log(params);
    lexruntime.postContent(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            session.userData = data.sessionAttributes;
            console.log(data);           // successful response
            session.send("%s", data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

I tested this on emulator provided by Microsoft and getting the response from my Lex Bot.

You can refer [PostContent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) for params content.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no native support for AWS Lex to integrate with Skype.

However, you can create a middleware that will use a Skype chat bot and forward requests on to AWS Lex. There are a number of different ways to do this so I won't provide any specifics.

Alternatively, Microsoft is also pitching [a chatbot framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) that is leveraging Cortana.

Comment: Can you provide any blog or example on github anythere for skype middleware integration ? @Milk

Comment: @surajrawat you need to send requests from your bot to AWS API gateway, this api gateway will forward the requests to your Lex bot.
Here's an example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/integrate-your-amazon-lex-bot-with-any-messaging-service/